# Domain Name Suffixes

Tags: dns

Not sure if this is a new thing, but I've begun to notice a lot of sites moving away from traditional .com-ending domain names to things like .ly, .us, etc as parts of their name (mir.aculo.us, bit.ly).

Are there any security issues to starting your website with one of these?  I was thinking about getting a .ly one, but found that they can be much more expensive than the ~$10/yr registration I can get with some .com's.  Would I be subject to that country's laws/taxes?

Are there any other endings people like besides .ly?

Any other issues y'all have encountered.

Looking forward to hearing what y'all think.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has [a list of top level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) (`.com`, `.ly`, etc) that contains some information on restrictions per TLD. For instance, not anyone can obtain a `.int`, `.mil`, or `.gov` address, but most of the other typical TLDs are open and anyone can obtain one. As for country TLDs, that list has some information on restrictions. Most of them are open, but some require various levels of restrictions. For instance, `.al` (Albania) requires citizenship while `.ee` (Estonia) is open but requires local contact.

As far as `.ly` domains being more expensive, `bit.ly` is a domain hack. It's supposed to be read aloud like "bitly". There are so many existing country domains that I suggest you just be a little creative and find another one (you could get your own domain for your username by registering `tarab.yt`). I'm sure you could find one that's not too costly.

As far as tax laws go, there isn't much information around this floating about. You can most certainly contact the local country which you are intending to register with.

Comment: Thanks for the thought-out response kelloti!  Looks like you godaddy.com doesn't have a lot of the domain suffixes available to buy.Would still love to hear more comments.

Comment: I did a little more research and it looks like a lot of the TLDs have second level domains (i.e. `.co.gg`, `.gov.gg`. I'm disappointed because I wanted to reserve `timkello.gg` but it looks like its not allowed). The TLDs that have obvious domain hacks in the English language seemed to have reserved many domains immediately and then setup their second-level domains. You'll definitely have to pay through the nose to get a cool domain hack.